# In a similar manner as SQL injection, is it possible to exploit text-entry fields?

Tags: web, sql-injection, exploit, web-testing

For example, it would make sense that in a comment section on a website which does not prevent the processing of escape characters that an escape character followed by code could *"infiltrate"* the backend code. How do big websites prevent this and is it absolutely impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not impossible.

Big websites and small websites prevent SQL injection exactly the same way:

**Using query parameters.**

This works for text fields as well as shorter strings, dates, numbers, etc.

Here's a hypothetical example in PHP, but similar examples exist for any other programming language.

```
$text = $_POST['textfield'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (textcol) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute( [ $text ] );
```

By keeping the content separate from the SQL query until `execute()`, this avoids a risk of SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good insight.